# Seeking advice from our Sages and Tanach about the dangers of 'national polarity'

Tags: pirke-avot-ethicsof, machlokes, politics-government, shalom-bayit

Regardless of where you sit on the political divide regarding the situation in the United States it seems as if the country is being devoured by polarity.  I am searching for advice from chazal regarding the dangers of polarity and possible remedies so that we can G-d-Willing restore peace and not lead to endless bickering and name calling and hate.

One source I found compelling was Rabbi Chanina's advice in [Pirkei Avot (3:2)](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.3.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

רבי חנינה סגן הכוהנים אומר , הוי מתפליל בשלומה של מלכות, שלמלא מוראה, איש את רעהו חיים בלעו

Can you suggest other sources ?  I am most interested here in National "Shalom Bayis" . I am not interested hearing your side of the political debate. Please keep your responses respectful . Thank you

Comment: Chazal's discussions of Shalom in general could easily be applied to the dangers of political discord